# Locally testing Azure Functions with DocumentDB (client library) and receiving 'Invalid API version' for 1.13.2 to 1.17.0

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm testing Azure Functions locally using VS2017 (Preview 7.1). The function writes to DocumentDB locally using the emulator (1.11.136.2) and everything works fine when using Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB 1.13.1. As soon as I upgrade to any of the newer versions (1.13.2 to 1.17.0), I receive the following error:

> Invalid API version. Ensure a valid x-ms-version header value is passed.

When calling the function from Postman I add a x-ms-version: 2017-02-22 header, but I suspect this is required only for the REST API.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AzureFunction
{
public static class Function1
{

    private static readonly ConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy =
        new ConnectionPolicy
        {
            UserAgentSuffix = " tilt",
            ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
            ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp,
             EnableEndpointDiscovery = false,                                   
        };

    [FunctionName("FunctionApp")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "func/app")]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
    {

        string setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DOCUMENTDB"];

        string databaseName = "test1";

        Tuple<Uri, string> conn = Connection(setting);
        using (var client = new DocumentClient(conn.Item1, conn.Item2, connectionPolicy))
        {

            // error thrown at next line
            await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database { Id = databaseName });
        }

        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    }

    static Tuple<Uri, string> Connection(string configSetting)
    {
        string[] setting = configSetting.Split(';');
        string endpoint = setting[0].Split('=')[1];
        string key = setting[1].Split('=')[1] + "==";
        var t = new Tuple<Uri, string>(new Uri(endpoint), key);
        return t;
    }
}
}
```

I could continue using 1.13.1, but I would like to start using Graph DB which is not compatible with this version.

Why am I receiving this error for the client library, and why only from version 1.13.2?

Comment: Just walked through the process from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-graph-dotnet which uses Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB 1.14.0 and received the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the emulator was the incorrect version. For Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB 1.14.0 and above, Azure DocumentDB Emulator 1.13.58.2 is required, which I installed from here https://chocolatey.org/packages/azure-documentdb-emulator.

Seems this site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator points to the old version.

Comment: This is most likely an issue with the Azure Functions tooling used. The version of the emulator downloaded from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator is 1.16.7.1 which has the correct x-ms-version used by the latest DocumentDB SDK client(1.17.0). I was able to verify this outside of the Azure functions scenario, wherein I was able to connect to the latest emulator available from the link above using the latest DOCUMENTDB SDK 1.17.0